# Trouble using find element in URL 2

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm very new at this so apologies if this is a silly question. I am trying to use Selenium to automate a form filling process. I have managed to automate the login details on URL 1. URL 1 then redirects me to URL 2 where I'm supposed to input data that will then redirect me to URL 3. The problem I'm facing is that the find elements command for the second URL does not seem to be working.

HTML code for URL 2 is as follows:
`input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtNofNo" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtNofNo" class="standardtextbox"`

`

[code I've tried so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjF40.jpg)
I've edited this code based on suggestions:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
time.sleep(10)
newURl = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to.window(newURl)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'NofNo')]").sendKeys("Selenium");
```

And I'm now getting the following error messages.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> newURl = driver.window_handles[0]   File "C:\Users\kg3517\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 724, in window_handles
> return self.execute(Command.W3C_GET_WINDOW_HANDLES)['value']   File
> "C:\Users\kg3517\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 321, in execute
> self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\kg3517\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 242, in check_response
> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) WebDriverException: chrome not reachable   (Session info:
> chrome=90.0.4430.212)

I suspect the problem mainly arises because of the change in URL but am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Can you please post your code in the question instead of attaching an image?

Comment: Seems that the locator for that element should be built relatively to some other parent element with more clear and unique attributes. Can you share the link to that page?

Comment: I'm afraid it requires specific login details. Is there something in particular I should be looking out for?

Comment: @krapple : When it redirects to 2nd URL then it happens in same tab or in new tab or windows ?

Comment: @cruisepandey- it opens in the same tab